# how to check if a list contains a sublist

Tags: groovy

```
def l = ["My", "Homer"]
String s = "Hi My Name is Homer"

def list = s.split(" ")
println list

list.each{it ->
    l.each{it1 ->
        if (it == it1)
            println "found ${it}"
    }
}
```

I want to check whether big list (`list`) contains all elements of sublist (`l`)
Does groovy have any built in methods to check this or what I have in the above code will do?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could use Groovy's `Collection.intersect(Collection right)` method and check whether the returned Collection is as big as the one that's passed as argument.

You have to use the `String.tokenize()` method before to generate a List from the String instead of `String.split()` which returns a String array:

```
def sublist = ["My", "Homer"]
def list = "Hi My Name is Homer".tokenize()

assert sublist.size() == list.intersect(sublist).size()
```

Alternatively, you could use Groovy's `Object.every(Closure closure)` method and check if each element of the sublist is contained in the list:

```
assert sublist.every { list.contains(it) }
```

However, the shortest way is using the standard Java Collection API:

```
assert list.containsAll(sublist)
```

Answer (score 9):

The easiest method is just to call:

```
list.containsAll(l)
```

You can find more information about it here: [Groovy Collections](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN1015-Collections)

Comment: Edit queue is full, like above is broken, see: http://groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#_working_with_collections

Answer (score -2):

Your solution will work. Be sure to consider the [Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) if you're dealing with large arrays of relatively few discrete values.

Comment: He wasn't asking if his solution would work or not, he was asking if there were any built in functions that he could use to do this instead.