# Python If Statements to Java

Tags: java, python, if-statement

I have this code in Python:

```
if word[x:x+2] in twowords:
```

(`twowords` is a list). I can't figure out how to write `in twowords` in Java.

Comment: So, check for a sublist? [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1872889/645270) was my first hit for that.

Comment: Perhaps he was looking for something in [java] or maybe he didn't know it's called a sublist.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Python uses `[x:y]` to create a substring.  You can use the [`substring` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) for that purpose, with the same parameters.

There is no `in` syntax in Java, but all `List`s in Java support the [`contains` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-).

Try

```
if (twowords.contains(word.substring(x, x+2)))
```

Comment: The colon is known as the slice operator by the way, IIRC.