# Check if sublist is in list in the same order

Tags: java, arrays, list, compare, sublist

I am trying to find a way to check if the elements of one list appears in another list in the same order in Java. For example:

```
char[] list = {'A','B','B','C','B','D'};
char[] sublist = {'B','C','B'};
char[] sublist2 = {'A','B','D'};
```

It should return true for sublist, but return false for sublist2 (because they do not appear in the same order). I am mainly trying to use for loops with some whiles and some ifs (trying not to use some built in functions maybe other than length).

I tried this but I do not think it is correct (getting wrong answers):

```
public static boolean subList(char[] list, char[] sublist) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sublist.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
            if (sublist[i] == list[j]) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return true; 
    }
    return false;
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a list contains a sublist in a given order in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32864977/how-to-check-if-a-list-contains-a-sublist-in-a-given-order-in-java)

Comment: @azurefrog does not work because char[] cannot be converted to List<>

Comment: *getting wrong answers* Which wring answers, please? Please be concrete and specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the most correct code but it works!

```
public static boolean subList(char[] list, char[] sublist) {
    int subposition = 0;
    boolean subarray = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (subposition < sublist.length) {
            if (list[i] == sublist[subposition]) {
                subposition++;
            } else if (subposition > 0) {
                subposition = 0;
                i--;
            }

            if(subposition == sublist.length) {
                subarray = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return subarray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
public static boolean subList(char[] list, char[] sublist) {
    L: for (int i = 0, max = list.length - sublist.length; i <= max; i++) {
        for (int j = 0, k = i; j < sublist.length; j++, k++)
            if (sublist[j] != list[k])
                continue L;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    char[] list = {'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'D'};
    char[] sublist = {'B', 'C', 'B'};
    char[] sublist2 = {'A', 'B', 'D'};
    System.out.println(subList(list, sublist));
    System.out.println(subList(list, sublist2));
}
```

output:

```
true
false
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work:

- outer loop by list, nested loop by sublist
- create a boolean flag `found`
- in the nested loop compare elements of `list` *starting* from *current* position in the list, as soon as discrepancy is detected, `found` is reset to false
- if upon completing the nested loop, `found` is `true` then the sublist is detected.

```java
public static boolean subList(char[] list, char[] sublist) {
    for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        boolean found = true;
        for(int j = 0, k = i; j < sublist.length && found && k < list.length; j++, k++) {
            if (sublist[j] != list[k]) {
                found = false;
            }
        }
        if (found) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Tests:

```java
char[] list = {'A','B','B','C','B','D'};
char[] sublist = {'B','C','B'};
char[] sublist2 = {'A','B','D'};        
System.out.println(subList(list, sublist));  // true
System.out.println(subList(list, sublist2)); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortcut is to convert each `char` array to a `String` since `String` has a `contains` method that gives us the answer that we want. `contains()` accepts any `CharSequence` as argument, so a `String` works, and a possibly slightly cheaper variant is to wrap `sublist` and `sublist2` in `CharBuffer`s rather than converting them too to `String`.

```
char[] list = { 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'D' };
char[] sublist = { 'B', 'C', 'B' };
char[] sublist2 = { 'A', 'B', 'D' };

String listString = new String(list);
System.out.println("Contains sublist? " + listString.contains(CharBuffer.wrap(sublist)));
System.out.println("Contains sublist2? " + listString.contains(CharBuffer.wrap(sublist2)));
```

Output:

> ```
> Contains sublist? true
> Contains sublist2? false
> ```

### What went wrong in your code?

What happens in your inner `for` loop doesn’t matter since after the loop finishes you unconditionally return `true`. So if `sublist` has length at least 1 (is not empty), you will reach that `return statement` and return `true`. If `sublist` is empty, the outer `for` loop is skipped, so you get down to the bottom of the method and return `false` (in spite of the empty list conventionally being regarded as contained in any list).

Instead from each position in `list` (not `sublist`) you need to search for a position where the chars from the two lists are *different*. If you find such a difference, the sublist is not contained at the current position in `list`, and you should try the next position.